# .htaccess redirect subdirectory uri but not the subdirectory itself

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I feel like I'm fairly close to this, but it's not quite right.

I'm trying to redirect anything after /subdirectory/ (Example: /subdirectory/admin) to the web root.  For example **/subdirectory/admin** would redirect to **/admin**

But, I would like to still be able to go to /subdirectory/ the problem is that **/subdirectory/** is also redirecting to **/**

Here is what I have and it works except that it still also redirects /subdirectory/

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subdirectory/(.*) http://example.com/$1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Because of the use of `.+` after `subdirectory/` it will match `subdirectory/foo` or `subdirectory/bar` but will not match `subdirectory/`.